# Setting back ground image of ios application dynamically using 3 sliders

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to set the background image for my ios application dynamically using 3 sliders for RED,GREEN and BLUE of value 0-255. How can this be done??

I should be able to dynamically change background color on slider adjustment.
Please help..

Comment: You can use `+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha` for synthesize color from values of your sliders and then set it color for background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get color of slider and set.

```
-(void)sliderChange:(id)sender
{
   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1stSlider.value/255.0 green:2ndSlider.value/255.0 blue:3rdSlider.value/255.0 alpha:1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(colorChanger) withObject:Nil afterDelay:0.5f];


    -(void)colorChanger{
        switch (Random.nextInt(2)) {
            case 0:
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            }
                break;
            case 1:
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

tag all 3 sliders with 1,2,3
make slider range 0 to 1

add a common target function to all three slider

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)slider
{
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:slider1.value green:slider2.value blue:slider3.value alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: Why needed make slider range 0 to 255 and then divide it value to 255? Not easier to just use the value of slider? By default value of slider in range 0...1.

Comment: Yeah , you can also make slider range from 0 to 1

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko because use of not decimal value is batter to identify :)

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Perhaps. If the values ​​of the components to be used somewhere else other than the color synthesis.

Comment: and question also contain  "3 sliders for RED,GREEN and BLUE of value 0-255."